# LocalDB - New code-first databases no longer being created on default folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, ef-code-first, localdb

I'm using Entity Framework's Code-First and LocalDB, with the following connection string:

```
Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=MyApp;Integrated Security=True;
Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;
ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;
```

The instance and its database files were properly created inside this path:

```
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB
```

But I was messing around and I renamed then deleted the MSSQLLocalDB through Visual Studio's "SQL Server Object Explorer" and its files. Now that I created it back, all databases generated via EF Code First are being created inside my `%USERPROFILE%` folder, i.e. `C:\Users\Me`.

In "SQL Server Object Explorer", if I right click and "Add New Database", it shows the right path. Right clicking the instance then properties shows that "Default Database Location" is correct.

The registry is correctly configured:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\UserInstances\{9F44D466-A9BA-40E3-9DEA-21E0638C80A2}]
...
"DataDirectory"="C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\\Instances\\MSSQLLocalDB"
```

I tried to create a new instance through [SqlLocalDB Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqllocaldb-utility) with a different name, but it behaves the same way. Also tried rebooting, before and after deleting the instance, no success.

I also tried reinstalling. I uninstalled Visual Studio (Web and Desktop), MS Data Tools, MSSQL Compact and MS LocalDB, then reinstalled VS, but no success.

I don't want to change my connection string and point it to the correct path, since the project is shared and maintained by other developers.

How do I revert this behavior? I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Express.

Comment: The path is not a part of your connection string, so do you really have a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the path here (in registry):

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\UserInstances]
```

The path is not a part of your connection string, so do you really have a problem?

Comment: Yes, I still have a problem, that registry key is set as `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB`.

Comment: After PC reboot?

Comment: Yes, I tried just rebooting, also tried rebooting after deleting the instance via `sqllocaldb` `stop` then `delete` and deleting its files, tried with a new instance via `sqllocaldb create LocalDB`.